# mahout recommender deployment as .war file on 0.9 version

Tags: mahout

I am new to mahout and web services related matters.

I have a huge problem concerning the deployment of a simple recommender as a .war file so far and that is because the steps followed by Manning Mahout Book - the only book found so far concerning mahout- refer to an older version of the platform.

I'm currently using mahout 0.9 which, with which i have created a recommender app that successfully runs on my IDE. However when it comes to the deployment of this project i can't find a step-by-step guide to handle my problem.

Does anyone have a clue on how to deploy a 0.5+ mahout project as a .war file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .war packaging was removed years ago. There is no means to deploy this that just gives you a web app. It is a library only.

Comment: I saw your response the day you replied, its just that i was so busy to find a solution that i didnt reply. Thank you and I fixed it like 2 days later by taking the source files and making a new web project from scratch.